# Zend Framework 2 directory organization

Tags: zend-framework2

Can someone propose best organization of directory structure for ZF2. For example I have:

- several Controller helpers,
- custom View hwlpers
- additional libraries like PHPExcel
- custom classes
- Auth, ACL classes
- Event handlers, so on

So which is the best(well read) directory organization for this.

Answer (score 4):

There are two structures: an application structure and a module structure.

**Applications**

The default and recommended directory structure for your application is as follows:

```
config/
  autoload/
module/
public/
vendor/
```

There is a `config/application.config.php` file and inside the `config/autoload` directory you have application specific configuration which overrides any module specific configuration.

Inside the `module/` directory you put all your application modules. If you use 3rd party modules or you made some reusable modules, you better put those inside the `vendor/` directory. That way you have a clear distinction between application specific modules and non-application specific modules.

The `public/` is your webroot. There you have the `index.php` and you might put your styles, scripts and other assets there.

*Example*: a perfect example is to have a directory `PHPExcel` inside the `vendor/` directory.

**Modules**

A module has a default and recommended structure as follows:

```
MyModule/
  config/
  src/
    MyModule/
      Controller/
        Plugin/
      Form/
      Service/
      View/
        Helper/
  view/
```

All your php code goes into `src/`. Because `src/` follows the [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) standard, you have your top namespaces (`MyModule`) repeated inside the `src/` directory. Under this directory, you have all your module code.

Just like the helpers in Zend Framework 2 (`Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\SomePlugin`), I would put them inside the `Controller/Plugin` directory. For view helpers you have the same: analogue to `Zend\View\Helper\SomeHelper` I would suggest you put your helpers inside the `View/Helper` directory.

Then you're left with "custom classes", "auth, acl classses" and "event handlers, so on". This really depends on the work they do. I have sometimes a `Listeners/` directory in my module source, where event listeners are located. Acl and authentication can be stored inside `Auth/` and `Acl/` directories too. It just really depends on the case and here it is most important you follow PSR-0 and the source is encapsuled in a module.